# Printing output to three decimal places python

Tags: python, python-3.x, decimalformat

I have print statements of the form:

```
print("a = ", a, "b = ", b, "c = ", c)
```

where a, b, and c are floating point numbers. I want to print to three decimal places, and keep the print statements in the form they are in currently, if possible?

**Attempt**

Following a similar post, I attempted the following:

```
print(" %.3f a = ", a, "%.3f b = ", b, "%.3f c = ", c)
```

but this just printed "%.3f" in the print statement. Any suggestions on how to adjust my print statement?

Comment: `print(round(a,3))`

Comment: I Think that using round is not really what is wanted here even if it does the same result. 
You can use the string formatting operator like that `print("a = ","%.3f"%a , "b = ","%.3f"%b)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will truncate (not round) the printing to 3 decimal places:

```
print("a = {:.3f}, b = {:.3f}, c = {:.3f} ".format(a, b, c))
```

[edit:] Using [`f-strings`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html), the syntax is as follows:

```
print(f"{a = :.3f}, {b = :.3f}, { c= :.3f}")
```

If you need to, you can round first.